# Can I display personalized content based on a clicked link from another page in Sitecore 7.5?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, sitecore7.5

I'm trying to display personalized content on a page IF I have clicked on a specific link on a specific page.

Then, on a page that will contain personalization rules, a piece of personalized content will display, but only if I clicked specific link on a specific page If so, then display a piece of content.

I know there is a way to do this using query string parameters, but this would involve some coding.  I don't want to do that, I want to see if there is something out of the box that will let me do this.

Comment: Could this link be anywhere? I was thinking you could use the refer. The rule is called "where the referrer compares to specific value".

Comment: I thought so too, but I can't find a rule for "where the referrer compares to a specific value."

Comment: You are right. The rule I was looking at was in 8.1. In 7.5 the rule does not exist. I think you are left with this, which you have probably found already. http://www.craigtaylor.us/2013/12/creating-http-referrer-condition.html

Comment: Yea 8.1 you could do this fairly simply.  I am not sure if its available in 7.5.  But you could use content personalisation.  Thus you could say on the page with you link, this user is now a type 'x' and then say on the linked page, if the user is type 'x' display content 'y' otherwise display content 'q'.  Does it matter if they get to the page from the link page another way, or do they have to click the link?

Comment: They actually have to click the link.